# Get the user location during registeration process

Tags: users, google-maps, location

I am developing a drupal site along with the mobile application.
I want to store the latitude , longitude of the user who registers in my site... 
I can see there are many location based modules available but i want to use the one which affers the map ui on the registeration form and the user types 
in its address and through reverse geocoding i could fetch the latitude and longitude of that place.

Basically i need location module during registeration form
Thanks

Comment: It seems you're new to stackexchange, if the answer given is helpful, you can select it as the right answer by clicking on the checkbox you get when hovering over the vote up/down widget.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Drupal 6, the obvious answer would be use the [Location](http://drupal.org/project/location) and [Gmaps](http://drupal.org/project/gmap) or [OpenLayers](http://drupal.org/project/openlayers) module. I've used it on many many sites and it generally works well. Another very good alternative in Drupal 6 that I just found now is [HTML5 user geolocation](http://drupal.org/project/html5_user_geolocation), that looks awesome and its what drupal.org uses!

However if I was using Drupal 7, I would definitely use the [Geolocation Field](http://drupal.org/project/geolocation) module. I've tried it out and its really awesome and easy for users.